# Why isn't my code increasing the score on reward video ad watched?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob, ads, reward

When I click a button to load a reward video ad the score should double. Instead the reward ad plays and when I close after watching it, nothing happens. I am using public static variable points to get the score value from the in game scene to the level finished scene, and then I get the total score from player prefabs.
I am new to coding.

Bellow is code.

```
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Admob : MonoBehaviour
{

    private BannerView adBanner;
    private RewardBasedVideoAd adReward;
    int pointts;
    int Totalpointts;
    private string idApp, idBanner, idReward;
    bool saveit = false;
    float Timer;
    public Text TotalPointsText;
    public GameObject congratulationspop;
    //public WatchVideo x2coinsWatch;

    [SerializeField] Button BtnX2;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    [Obsolete]
    void Start()
    {
        //get data
        //
        idApp = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713";
        idBanner = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";
        idReward = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917";

        adReward = RewardBasedVideoAd.Instance;
        MobileAds.Initialize(idApp);

        Debug.LogWarning("Banner Ad Embeded");
        RequestBannerAd();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    public void GiveRewards()
    {
        BtnX2.interactable = false;
        BtnX2.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "Loading...";
        RequestRewardAd();
    }

    public void RequestBannerAd()
    {
        adBanner = new BannerView(idBanner, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Bottom);
        AdRequest request = AdRequestBuild();
        adBanner.LoadAd(request);
    }

    public void DestroyBannerAd()
   {
        if (adBanner != null)
        {
        adBanner.Destroy();
        }
   }

    public void RequestRewardAd()
    {
        AdRequest request = AdRequestBuild();
        adReward.LoadAd(request, idReward);

        adReward.OnAdLoaded += this.HandleOnRewardedAdLoaded;
        adReward.OnAdRewarded += this.HandleOnRewarded;
        adReward.OnAdClosed += this.HandleOnRewardedAdClosed;
    }

    public void ShowRewardAd()
    {
        if (adReward.IsLoaded())
        adReward.Show();
    }

    public void HandleOnRewardedAdLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args) // Ad Loaded
    {
        ShowRewardAd();
    }

    public void HandleOnRewardedAdOpening(object sender, EventArgs args) // Ad Opening
    {

    }

    public void HandleOnRewarded(object sender, EventArgs args) // User Finished Wacthing The Ad
    {
        // Funtion here to double the coins
        x2Thepoints();
    }

    public void HandleOnRewardedAdClosed(object sender, EventArgs args) // ad closed not watching the 
ad
    {
        BtnX2.interactable = false;
        BtnX2.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "X2 Points";
        //testing

        //testing till here
        adReward.OnAdLoaded -= this.HandleOnRewardedAdLoaded;
        adReward.OnAdRewarded -= this.HandleOnRewarded;
        adReward.OnAdClosed -= this.HandleOnRewardedAdClosed;
    }

    AdRequest AdRequestBuild()
    {
        return new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
         DestroyBannerAd();

        adReward.OnAdLoaded -= this.HandleOnRewardedAdLoaded;
        adReward.OnAdRewarded -= this.HandleOnRewarded;
        adReward.OnAdClosed -= this.HandleOnRewardedAdClosed;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    { 
        Totalpointts = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("points" , Totalpointts);
        TotalPointsText.text = "Total Points : " + Totalpointts;
        pointts = destination.Mypoint;

        Debug.Log(pointts);
        if (saveit == true)
        {
            Timer += Time.deltaTime;
            if (Timer >= 2f)
            {
                Points.inc.OnSavePoint();
                saveit = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public void x2Thepoints()
    {       
        Totalpointts += pointts;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("points", Totalpointts);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
        saveit = true;

        BtnX2.interactable = false;
        congratulationspop.SetActive(true);
        TotalPointsText.text = "Total Points : " + Totalpointts;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if related but: You shouldn't this `Totalpointts = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("points" , Totalpointts);` in `FixedUpdate` ... Did you try [debugging](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) with breakpoints and see which methods get called?

Comment: May I btw also ask why your `Start` is `[Obsolete]` ^^?

Comment: I don't know. I got some help from a developer. I paid him and he give me this code.

Comment: As @Lexicon said, try to put log in x2Thepoints() method to know if the method is called. If the log doesn't appear on the console, that means there is a problem with the callback method (HandleOnRewarded).

Answer (score -1):

Unity Google Ads callback events are not guaranteed to be called in the main Unity thread. Try to set you score this way:

```
public void HandleOnRewarded(object sender, EventArgs args) // User Finished Wacthing The Ad
{ 
    MobileAdsEventExecutor.ExecuteInUpdate(() =>
    {
        // Funtion here to double the coins
        x2Thepoints();
    });
}
```

The method `MobileAdsEventExecutor.ExecuteInUpdate` runs the callback in the main Unity thread (unity is mono thread).

Answer (score -1):

1. Set the ad related event handlers before 
   adReward.LoadAd(request, idReward);

   > ```
   > adReward.OnAdLoaded += this.HandleOnRewardedAdLoaded;
   > adReward.OnAdRewarded += this.HandleOnRewarded;
   > adReward.OnAdClosed += this.HandleOnRewardedAdClosed;
   > adReward.LoadAd(request, idReward);
   > ```
2. Event handlers are not guaranteed to execute in the Unity main thread. So, force execute them in the next update:

> ```
> public void HandleOnRewarded(object sender, EventArgs args)
> {
>    MobileAdsEventExecutor.ExecuteInUpdate(() => {
>     x2Thepoints();
>   });
> }
> ```

Comment: not worked.. maybe there is something wrong with my other score?

Comment: @Ben: I haven't copied from you and it seems you have edited your response from mine after my initial response -not a good way to increase your score I agree-, I can see the edit history FYI. 




Azhar: Could you please add Debug.Log("x2ThePoints called with "+TotalPointts) after the saveit=true in x2ThePoints() function and see if the message pops up in the console?

Comment: @Lexicon, I edited the syntax, not the code. And you edited you answere first, and you added my code :P. But nevermind we are here to help, not to fight ^^.